# How do I get top tweets for my search request using twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

```
public static void main() throws Exception {
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    ....build());
    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
    Query q=new Query("#technology");
    QueryResult search = twitter.search(q);
    for (Status s : search.getTweets().subList(0, 10)) {
        System.out.println(s.getText()+"\n Username -> "+s.getUser().getName());
    }
```

I want to get the top tweets under #technology and re-tweet them.
My current code gives me latest tweets for #technology.
Thanks in advance for the answer. Hope I was clear with my question.